# How to remove a keybinding for a special character?

Tags: keyboard, shortcut-keys

I keep running into a certain issue - pressing `Right-Alt + Spacebar` enters a non-breaking space. I don't really mind the extra byte of space it takes, but what grinds my gears is that `gcc` will refuse to compile anything until it is removed - and it is *extremely* difficult to get rid of without breaking my workflow.

I have tested whether this is something caused by my IDE of choice (Atom) by writing a hello world program in GTK and LibreOffice as well, and the result is the same (`Right-Alt + Space` inserts a non-breaking space). I've also tried replicating it in the Windows counterparts, where it does not happen.

So, since writing a preprocessor to use with all my projects is not a reasonable solution, how does one go about removing the keybinding for entering a non-breaking space?

Comment: This keypress is defined by your text editor. First check whether you can change/delete it in your editor. Alternatively, a system wide approach will be needed. Unfortunatelly, it is not possible to add a system wide shortcut for the Altright+Space keyboard combination. If that were the case, you could assign it a dummy function so it would not interfere with your programming.

Comment: @vanadium Occurs both in GTK and Atom (but not on Windows), so either someone's gone to the trouble of making an obscure and undocumented keybinding that only exists on Linux with both of those, or the issue stems from somewhere within Ubuntu.

Comment: You did not indicate the application where you have the issue. Your comment suggests that it might be Atom. Add this information to your post by editing it. If the issue is Atom specific, make sure Atom also appears in the title of your question.

Comment: @vanadium Like mentioned - it occurs in GTK *and* Atom. Two different frameworks. I went ahead and also tried it in Libre's Writer, and it is the same thing. However, I'll add the information to the question.

Comment: You will find a good overview of keyboard manipulation utilities here: http://xahlee.info/linux/linux_keyboard_tools.html. Probably you should be able to disable the key combination (glabally, though, not app specific) with xbindkeys.